# Silverlight binding to canvas, element location in list at element?

Tags: c#, silverlight, list, model

I have created a custom user control, which is basicly a `ItemsControl` with it's `ItemsPanelTemplate` set to canvas.

On the mainpage I bind a `List<Element>` to it, where Element is a custom class.

However, all the controls are placed right on top of eachother. A easy way to fix this ofcourse is by making the Canvas a WrapPanel but I'm not sure if this will colide with the ability of Drag & Drop on the control

So my question would be,  is it possible to have a property in the model `Element` which checks on which position it is of a list, if it is in a list?

something like:

```
public class Element 
{
    public int positionInList { get { return (this.IsInList) ? this.ListPosition : 0; } }
}
```

**Update**

What I wish to accomplish is that when the elements are added to the canvas, they automaticly pick their spot by 2 properties (which will be bound to the Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top or something similar)

```
public double GetX { get { return 50 * (Element.PositionInList % 5); } }
public double GetY { get { return 50 * (Element.PosotionInList / 5); } }
```

Without manually having to set the element's position in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you place elements in a Canvas, you must specify the coordinates where the elements will be placed (left upper corner for each element). Maybe is better to derivate from Canvas a new class that will perform the placement for you and use this class for ItemsPanelTemplate. Also, Drag & Drop should work with WrapPanel but depends on your requirements.

A quick and non optimal sample:

```
class CustomCanvas : Canvas
{
private int mChildsNum = 0;
...
CustomCanvas()
{
    // Track changes that appear in canvas when new
    // children are added
    this.LayoutUpdated += CanvasChangeTracker;
}
...
private void CanvasChangeTracker(object source, EventArgs e)
{
    if ( this.Children.Count != mChildsNum )
    {
        // A new child was added.
        // Update the coordinates for children
        mChildsNum = this.Children.Count;
    }
}
...
}
```

This example can be considerably improved.

Comment: Not sure wether we understand eachother.  I wish for the coordinates to be specified automaticly based on the position of the element in the list. See my update

Comment: The new class derived from Canvas can compute position when you add an element. An instance of this class knows how many children has and where to place a new child.

Comment: Could you perhaps give a small example since I don't fully understand what you mean.

Comment: Another way to solve the problem. You can use Canvas.SetTop and Canvas.SetLeft when you add the element in list.

Answer (score 0):

You need a custom panel, so you can create a class and inherits from `Panel` this will implements two methods to override

```
protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
```

Which you must implement.

Here is an example:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31537/Custom-Panel-in-Silverlight-Advanced-Canvas

Answer (score 0):

If you have properties GetX and GetY, you can do the same as the accepted answer here:

[Silverlight 3 - Data Binding Position of a rectangle on a canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637400/silverlight-3-data-binding-position-of-a-rectangle-on-a-canvas)

I would just reply to your post, since this is not really *my* answer, but I guess I don't have enough rep to reply.